# User get redirected to LogOn action in the middle of his work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The user uploads a file on server and I get data from that file. If the file is really large, this can take a lot of time. Nevertheless, after 10 minutes or so, the user get redirected to the Account/LogOn action method, right in the middle of the processing of the data.

Why is this happening? Is it something about his session? Or is it the routes?

Here's what I have in web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" name=".MYAUTH" path="/" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: Don't have enough info to tell what's wrong but look like your user's session has timed out while the file is transferring

Comment: Are you transferring the file synchronously?